# Mongodb complete db export and import

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, meteor

I need to export complete staging database and import into local database. As per my R&D only collections are being to export and import. Can anyone suggest how to import complete database and import into local.
I'm using **meteor** for development

Comment: Have you checked whether [mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongodump/) and [mongorestore](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongorestore/) are what you are looking for?

Comment: mongodump and mongorestoe are external commands and not bundled with meteor by default, you need to install them additionally

Answer (score 1):

By default, Meteor has built-in mongodb server running at port which equals to Meteor webserver port + 1. For example, if your Meteor runs at port 3000 then the mongodb runs at port 3001.
You can use mongodump and mongorestore to export and import database.

Comment: I'm having a database in atlas and  I need to import that database to local . Since meteor is running local it is dumping local database but i need server database  to dump into local meteor database

Comment: I am able to above things easily using studio 3t